# Android proguard console error

Tags: android, proguard

Here is my file

```
   -keep class com.droidux.** {*;}
   -keep interface com.droidux.** { *;}
   -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {public static <fields>;}
   -keep class **.R$*
   -keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
   -keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
   -keepattributes *Annotation*
   -keep public class * extends       com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
   -keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
   -keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockMapActivity
   -keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
   -keepclassmembers class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock {
<init>(android.app.Activity, int);}
```

When I try to export, I get the following error.I search and get no results for fixing it.

> [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd: can't find referenced method 'java.io.File getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' in class android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: there were 37 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
>   [2015-07-20 11:24:32 - myapp] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to add

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

to your Proguard config file?